# Issue with rspec and gmaps4rails

Tags: rspec, gmaps4rails

I'm trying to convert a project to RSpec and am running into an issue with the gmaps4rails gem.  I don't have any specs written yet, though if I run the test suite I get:

...gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined method`acts_as_gmappable' for # (NoMethodError)

If I comment out the line in the model using gmaps4rails:
acts_as_gmappable :process_geocoding => false, :lat => "lat_coord", :lng => "long_coord"

everything runs fine (no tests run but no failures). With the line, I get the error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty clear, `gmaps4rails` no longer has an `acts_as_gmappable` method, from v 2.x

Comment: That was it, when I bundled in RSpec, I didn't notice that it upgraded gmaps4rails in the process, removing that method.  Thanks for the pointer.